# How to programmatically copy excel worksheet sheet to a new one

Tags: python, excel

I have created a python script that parses some data and uses it to generate a few worksheet excel files (xlsx) (I am not much knowledgeable in excel by the way).

The original worksheet i am reading the data from has a main sheet used to fill in lots of info which is then distributed across many other sheets, which perform some formulas to calculate some results.

My python script does the processing i want by automatically filling in this main sheet, which then produces the results of the other sheets. I then save the worksheet and eveything looks fine.

Now, I want to split those worksheets into individual ones without including the main sheet in any of them. This appears to be pretty challenging.

I first tried using the data_only argument of load_workbook, but I quickly discovered that in order to preserve the values and not the formulas in the spreadsheet(or just get None back), I'd have to manually open and save each one of the files so that a temporary cache is created. That won't really do it in my case since i want the whole thing to be automated.

Among other things, the one that came closer is this piece of code:

```
workbook = xw.Book('generatedFiles/generated.xlsx')
sheet1 = workbook.sheets['PRIM'].used_range.value
df = pd.DataFrame(sheet1)
df.to_excel('generatedFiles/fixed-generated.xlsx', index = False, header = False)
```

This does indeed generate a spreadsheet with the values, using its pandas dataframe, but the problem is that it doesn't preserve any information about the types of the values. So for example, an integer is being treated as a string when saved.

This messes the processing being done by an external parser that I feed these files with.

Any ideas on how to fix that ? What would be the best way to go about doing something like that ?

Thanks !

Comment: Why not do a save as of the complete workbook then delete the sheet or sheets from the duplicate.

Comment: @SolarMike Tried that, loses the references and so the calculated fields get removed. And I do want to remove the original placeholder sheet.

Comment: Then remove the references: copy : paste special values. Check out a question I have in here for master sheet in the title...

Comment: You mean manually ? I need to do this programmatically. I could also copy paste to new spreadsheets if i wanted to do it manually. Basically I want to be doing this without opening up Excel.

Comment: Manually search on here...